# Fast way to convert array to tuple/list in python?

Tags: python, numpy, mysql-python

It seems like the time it takes to convert an array to a tuple scales linearly with the the length of the array. Is there a way to do this more efficient? I need to insert arrays with 5e+6 elements into a mysql database, but MySQLdb only seems to accept tuples or lists as input to insertmany.

Comment: How about using [h5py](http://code.google.com/p/h5py/) or [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/) instead of MySQL?

Comment: As data copying needs constant time per item, I don't suppose that yo can get better than linear.

Comment: @glglgl: The need to copy the data only arises from interface restriction.  If you could avoid copying in the first place, that would be better than linear performance at least for that step.  (Of course inserting the data in the database would still be linear.)

Comment: I should also explain a bit more what I'm doing- I have five vectors with 5e+6 elements each where each position represents a row. Think particles with id, x- y- z-position, and time. I need to insert this data to the database and hence either use zip or vstack to fit execute many. strangely enough, the conversion from vectors to a tuple of tuples is an order of magnitude slower than the insert to mysql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQLdb uses `re` and string interpolation to join parameterized SQL with arguments before passing the query to the server as a string. Clearly this is not the way to go -- not only are you converting the array to tuples, but also the tuples into strings.

In contrast [oursql](http://packages.python.org/oursql/) sends SQL queries to the MySQL server separate from data.

---

Since you have 5 arrays, using `zip` (or `column_stack`) would require Python (or numpy) to allocate more memory for the combined object (list of tuples or 2D numpy array). To avoid this, use [itertools.izip](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

```
import itertools as it
x=np.random.random(1e6)
y=np.random.random(1e6)
connection = oursql.connect(
    host=config.HOST, user=config.USER, passwd=config.PASS, db='test')
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql='INSERT INTO foo (x,y) VALUES (?,?)'
    cursor.executemany(sql,it.izip(x,y))
    print(cursor.lastrowid)
```

PS. Previously I suggested using `oursql.BinaryIterWrapper`. I wasn't able
to get that solution to work, however, perhaps because of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/oursql/+bug/737945).

PPS. I tried timing the above oursql code versus similar code using MySQLdb.
However, no timing was possible for MySQLdb since it raised

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1153, "Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes")
```

on `cursor.ecutemany(...)`.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the best solution. I just need to figure out how to install oursql on a Mac- I get a bunch of compilation errors.